# Retrieving and image that was uploaded using time() in its name

Tags: php, mysqli

I am very new to PHP programming. I am uploading pictures using a specific upload path and also time() so that new files do not overwrite old files that have the same name.

```
$target = EHS_UPLOADPATH . time() . $picture;
```

`if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], $target))`

and then the rest of the code.

This part is working well, no problems at all. The problem I am having is retrieving that picture to be displayed as part of the person's profile. This is the line of code I am using to try to do it:

```
echo '<img src="' . EHS_UPLOADPATH . time() . $row['picture'] . '" alt="Band Member Picture"/>';
```

The main problem is that when this line of code is run the server inputs the current time and not the time when the file was uploaded; therefore, the picture can't be retrieved and displayed. What's the best way then to retrieve a picture that has time() as part of its name then?

I checked for possible solutions on this website and didn't find the solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Store the full filename somewhere in a database and use that in your image src?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$picName = time() . $picture ;
$target = EHS_UPLOADPATH . $picName;
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], $target))
echo '<img src="' . EHS_UPLOADPATH . $row['picture'] . '" alt="Band Member Picture"/>';
```

You `$row['picture']` should contain the `$picName`, meaning you should store `$picName` in the picture column of your DB table

Also I think your understanding about time function is wrong. You cannot expect `time()` to return the same number even when you call it in the same page, I presume that you will be doing database operations after moving image and selecting before showing that in display page, you can never expect `time()` to be same. The best way, is to store `time()` in a variable and try it like the way mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It works perfectly now!!!! I am reading a book called "Head First PHP & MySql and they recommended to save the name as UPLOADPATH . time() . $picture ; however, after reading your comment I see why it can be a bad idea. I will continue using your method from now on ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need keep time() in DB. If you save image to DB. If not use DB see comment below.

`$time = time();`

`$target = EHS_UPLOADPATH . $time . $picture;`

1. Write time to DB with image.
2. And load time from DB with image

`echo '<img src="' . EHS_UPLOADPATH . $row['time'] . $row['picture'] . '" alt="Band Member Picture"/>';`